# Implementing a SSL trustmanager for google.com

Tags: java, ssl, https, x509certificate, trustmanager

I am trying to implement a custom ssl trustmanager for google.com.
I exported the certificate in DER encoded binary X.509(.CER) format from google.com 
using the certificate export wizard in chrome.

Next I am using the certificate to implement a X509TrustManager for google.com

I am converting the certificate into an array of X509Certificate.
I am doing a check on the public key of the exported certificate and the certificate chain which I get from google
in checkServerTrusted() method.

This is my implementation

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.security.interfaces.ECPublicKey;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase;
import org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Sequence;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.AlgorithmIdentifier;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.SubjectPublicKeyInfo;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier;
import org.jboss.security.Base64Encoder;

public class GetCertificates {
    static private TrustManager[] trustmgr = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {

        private X509Certificate[] compCerts = null;

        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            System.out.println("checkClientTrusted");
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            boolean match = false;
            compCerts = getcompanyCerts("C:/Users/vinod/Desktop/certificate tests/googleCert.cer");

            for (int i = 0; i < certs.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < compCerts.length; j++) {
                    PublicKey pubKey = compCerts[j].getPublicKey();
                    if (certs[i].getPublicKey().equals(pubKey)) {
                        match = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!match) {
                compCerts = null;
                throw new CertificateException();
            }

            System.out.println("checkServerTrusted");
        }

        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            System.out.println("getAcceptedIssuers");
            return compCerts;
        }
    } };

    public void postMessage() {
        try {

            String server = "google.com";//github.com, google.com, 
            int port = 443;
            String protocol = "https";
            String authData = "";
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sslContext.init(null, trustmgr, new SecureRandom());
            SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(sslContext, new AllowAllHostnameVerifier());
            Scheme httpsScheme = new Scheme("https", port, sf);
            SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
            schemeRegistry.register(httpsScheme);
            ClientConnectionManager cm = new SingleClientConnManager(schemeRegistry);
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(cm);
            HttpResponse httpClientResponse = null;
            HttpRequestBase httpBase = null;

            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(protocol + "://" + server + ":" + String.valueOf(port));

            httpGet.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + authData);
            httpGet.addHeader("accept", "application/xml");
            httpBase = httpGet;
            httpClientResponse = httpclient.execute(httpBase);
            System.out.println(httpClientResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static X509Certificate[] getcompanyCerts(String path)
    {
        try
        {
            X509Certificate x509Certificate[] = null;
            ArrayList<X509Certificate> serverCerts = new ArrayList<X509Certificate>();
            Certificate cert = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCertificate(new FileInputStream(path));
            X509Certificate cert1 = (X509Certificate) cert;
            serverCerts.add(cert1);
            x509Certificate = serverCerts.toArray(new X509Certificate[serverCerts.size()]);
            return x509Certificate;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GetCertificates().postMessage();
    }

}
```

**Public key from the certificate which I exported**

Sun EC public key, 256 bits
public x coord: 103858512549833402870596711608983633962395322362485707804776545539526450437829
public y coord: 551038063834479125183333778395955290333878428073207984470499584820613530179
parameters: secp256r1 [NIST P-256, X9.62 prime256v1] (1.2.840.10045.3.1.7)

**Public key from google certificate chain**

Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
modulus: 23143370852942880318350916000931697018095187779007718496802621885454913199787528262130121558631489120838817008741156066278392137072461769922534717322344763991314852008921195771153223806536069497781120172866861790294120988948493270866849076947675153622229006495917543748035309441307004545650688546140739858567714350881927672977958435382326618077408774333432728249263290793965486643049909764375831461262493963698376698137704130984951477859888660854457689871626252787358108605089635723759571477994625181232277846364760559779436524005104837073250536963577409319433417664849201259083657597612256894368314574080046815497557
public exponent: 65537

Exported certificate gives **Sun EC public key, 256 bits** but certificate from google gives **Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits**.
Where am I going wrong. Is the way in which I exported the certificate wrong or any mistake with the way in which I am converting the certificate to X509Certificate.

Comment: Google.com is a heavily distributed system which consists of hundreds of computers in dozens of server locations all over the world. That not all computers are equipped with the same certificate may happen in such environments. AFAIR Google prefers CA certificate pinning instead of server certificate pinning.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am very new to this area. do you mean I need to check only for valid CA in case of google, because the same code works for github.com with github's certificate.

Comment: You can try to pin the intermediate CA `Google Internet Authority G2` for google or the root CA `GeoTrust Global CA`. For both CAs it is very unlikely that someone will get a forged google.com certificate.